# VBA continuous sum loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, sum

I am trying to create loop which is summing numbers in column N until certain value is reach then write something to cell M.
I have this code working but what I actualy need is to after it found the set value to go to next row and start from 0 untill it finds again the value and then again go to next line and sum from 0 to some value.

Example of data

```
INV SIZE of INV
26530492    1
26530520    1
26530521    1
26530523    1
26530527    1
26530528    1
26531080    1
26531083    1
26531112    1
26531114    1
26543723    1
26543737    1
26556566    1
26556893    1
```

in first column are invoices and second column is showing size of the file. The loop would go throug Size column and sum rows until value is reached like 5, then it will continue until another value is reached and so on...it will also add condition to new column like first sum is number 1, second sum 2, etc..

also I am playing with code below

```
    Sub Sum_loop()

'~~> j stands for number of summed segment  
        j = 1
        dbSumTotal = 0
        lastrow = Range("N" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastrow Step 1
'~~> in column N are numbers for sum
            dbSumTotal = dbSumTotal + Cells(i, "N")

            If (dbSumTotal >= 3 Or dbSumTotal <= 3) Then
            Cells(i, "O") = j
'~~> reset sum to 0 
            If dbSumTotal >= 3 Then 
               dbSumTotal = 0
'~~> for next sum raise the segment number
               j = j + 1
              End if
            End If
        Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: PS. Don't do string math. Replace `Range("M1:M" & lastrow)` with `Range("M1").Resize(lastrow,1)`.

Comment: What is `cell = cell & "1"` supposed to do? If it supposed to append to the value use `cell.Value = cell.Value & "1"`, but if it is supposed to increment the current cell, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: its adding 1 to string it just example in the code, I am normaly using .value

Comment: @FilipOndo I suggest you add screen-shot of your data, and some manual example of what you are trying to achieve, I'm quite sure we will be able to offer a more reliable solution.

Comment: Also, put in your actual code - this is a small enough proc that you don't need an MVCE. If you're normally using `.Value` then use it.

Comment: thanks, I added more details

Comment: I _think_ that the problem is in `cell = cell & "1"`. I think you're trying to use that to jump your `For` index forward and you cannot do that in a `For Each` loop. If you're trying to increment your loop index outside of the normal loop mechanism (i.e. auto-increment at `Next`), then you need to use a regular `For` loop, not `For Each`.

Comment: So actualy the last code is working almost as I wanted :) I will try to adapt it more for my case

Comment: Just a note: Don't ever use `On Error Resume Next` without error handling! This line just hides any errors but they still occur, you just cannot see them. Remove it, or implement a proper error handling instead.

Comment: @FreeMan you are right

Comment: @Pᴇʜ it is there only for some testing, I am not using it otherwise

Comment: Looking at your final loop, I'm lost in the meaningless loop index names. Give them useful names so nobody has to ask "What does `j` represent?".

Comment: Testing is the **worst** time to use `OERN`! It hides every error, pretending it doesn't exist. It should be used sparingly and only when you know exactly what you're doing and why you're doing it. If you permanently delete that line, you'll probably see _exactly_ what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @FreeMan I know, I had it there because I had type mistmatch in row 1, stupid I know but the issue was somewhere else and in the end I will use second code I will just delete the first one.

Comment: `If (dbSumTotal >= 3 Or dbSumTotal <= 3) Then` is _ALWAYS_ true for _any_ value of `dbSumTotal` it will always be less than, equal to or greater than `3`. What are you really looking for?

Comment: its hit second if when dbSumTotal is 3 and for all row before it will write j value which in first sum is 1. then it reset to dbSumTotal and add 1 to j so its 2 and then sum until it hit 3 again and so on

Comment: I would remove the `cells = j` part out of your if statement, that could reduce one entire if statement from your code.

Comment: Include a sample (based on the sample data you provided) of the output you're currently getting, then a sample of what you are actually after. That would help me, at least get a better understanding of where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is messed up. The first if statement can never be true. Remove it completely and write the cell value after the counter is incremented.

```
Sub Sum_loop()

'~~> j stands for number of summed segment  
        j = 1
        dbSumTotal = 0
        lastrow = Range("N" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastrow Step 1
'~~> in column N are numbers for sum
            dbSumTotal = dbSumTotal + Cells(i, "N")
'~~> write value to cell and reset sum to 0 
            If dbSumTotal >= 3 Then  
               dbSumTotal = 0
'~~> for next sum raise the segment number
               j = j + 1
            End If
            Cells(i, "O") = j                   
        Next i

    End Sub
```